# Is it possible to force data immutability in a python function?

Tags: python, immutability

Say I define a list object and only want it to be read-only in a function I define. In C++, you'd do this with a const reference. Is there any way to do this with a python function? Does this make sense with respect to writing "pythonic" code or am I just trying to apply a C++ paradigm incorrectly?

Comment: Use a tuple instead of a list.

Comment: In Python mutability is a feature of the type, not specific instances or variables.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `tuple`, instead:

```
>>> hash([1,2,3])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    hash([1,2,3])
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
>>> hash((1,2,3))
2528502973977326415
>>>
```

`hash` can define whether it is mutable or not, and produces an error of `TypeError: unhashable type` if it's mutable, such as `list`s, OTOH `tuple` will return some large numbers (don't need to care in this particular case), we can use a `try` `except` if you want to:

```
try:
    hash((1,2,3))
    print('Immutable object')
except:
    print('Mutable object')
```

Which outputs:

```
Immutable object
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, all variables are references, so having an equivalent of C's `const` wouldn't really do anything. If the pointed-to object is mutable, you can mutate it; if it's immutable, you can't.

However, there are some types that are mutable, and some that aren't. Lists are mutable, but tuples are not. So if you pass your data as a tuple, you're guaranteed the function can't do anything to it.

To use a C metaphor, a list of integers is somewhat like an `int[]`, and a tuple of integers is a `const int[]`. When you pass them to a function, it doesn't matter if you're passing a `const` reference or a non-`const` reference; what matters is whether *the thing it references* is `const` or not.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `tuple` is the most common way to do this, as explained in the other answers.  Assuming you are starting with a `list` instance, other possible strategies include:

- if the role of the list in the function is just to be looped over, pass an iterator rather than the list itself - `iterator = iter(my_list)`.  Note that the you can only loop over the iterator once; if you need to loop more than once you could pass a generator that repeatedly yields `iter(my_list)`.
- pass copy of the list instead of the list itself: `new_list = my_list.copy()` or `new_list = my_list[:]`.  This may not be a good strategy for very large lists, due to memory consumption.

Whichever method you choose - even tuples - be aware that these approaches all assume that the elements in the collection are themselves immutable, for example integers and strings.  If the elements are mutable then they can be mutated (but not replaced):

```
>>> t = ([1], [1,2])
>>> t[0] = 6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
>>> t[0][0] = 6
>>> t
([6], [1, 2])


>>> L = [[1], [1, 2]]
>>> for x in iter(L):
...     x[0] += 1
... 
>>> L
[[2], [2, 2]]

>>> L = [[1], [1, 2]]
>>> copy = L.copy()
>>> for x in copy:
...     x[0] += 1
... 
>>> L
[[2], [2, 2]]
>>> 

>>> copy[0] = 42
>>> copy
[42, [2, 2]]
>>> L
[[2], [2, 2]]
```

You can workaround this by using [copy.deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy), but again at a cost in memory.